# How can I improve this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, question-quality

I have asked this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/347035/98471), but I am not even getting any comments. I am not sure if this has some issue.

Can somebody help me improve the question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for UNIX & Linux. Given it's really asking for help with the c/c++ module for Nginx I've migrated it to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you. Hope someone will be able to help me :)